how to multiple delete rows with selectableRange : true,..?
i am using tabulator version 6.2 javascript,, when using selectableRows: true, multiple delete rows is working, but when using selectableRange: true, it doesnt,, how to do it? i am use selectableRange because clipboard feature, in selectableRows clipboard feature can't be use
i use tabulator as interactive table and can be crud on table, i try to make multi delete feature when i use selectableRow: true, its work as well, but when i use selectableRange: true, its only remove one row that where i am right click on that, i make a custom contextmenu with, rowContext

Using
this.table.getRanges().map(range => range.getRows().map(row => row.getPosition()))

Later, you get the position,
let row = this.table.getRowFromPosition(position); // Get the row using the position 
this.table.deleteRow(row); // Delete the row

